# Can't access javascript class from within jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have this function inside of a javascript class:

```
this.checkSections = function(){
        jQuery('#droppable #section').each( function() {
            nextId = jQuery(this).next().attr('id');
            if (nextId != 'small' && nextId != 'large'){
                jQuery(this).remove();
                this.sections --;
                this.followArticles = 0;
            }else{
                articles = 0;
                obj = jQuery(this).next();
                while (nextId == 'small' || nextId == 'large'){
                    articles++;
                    obj = obj.next()
                    nextId = obj.attr('id');
                    //alert(nextId);
                }
                this.followArticles = articles;
                alert(this.sections);
            }
        });
    }
```

the `alert(this.sections);` (last lines) gives output of `undefined` although the `sections` is defined and used.

what could be the problem?

Comment: `this` does not relate to what you think it does. jQuery has overwritten it for use in `$(this)`. I'm sure there is another method that's simpler, but I always use underscore.js's `_.bind()` function to pass through the parent's `this` data.

Comment: Inside the each function, `this` would be the element being iterated, and you're using `$(this).remove()` on the line above, so what makes you think `this` would reference a class on the next line ?

Comment: did you try alerting this.sections.value();

Comment: [Javascript: How to access a class attribute from a function within one of the class's functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429487/javascript-how-to-access-a-class-attribute-from-a-function-within-one-of-the-cl?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

`this` is always a local variable and therefore it is overwritten in every function.

What you might do is pointing to your class e.g. `var myClass = this;` and use `myClass` instead of `this`.

```
 this.checkSections = function(){

    var myClass = this;

    jQuery('#droppable #section').each( function() {
        nextId = jQuery(this).next().attr('id');
        if (nextId != 'small' && nextId != 'large'){
            jQuery(this).remove();
            myClass.sections --;
            myClass.followArticles = 0;
        }else{
            articles = 0;
            obj = jQuery(this).next();
            while (nextId == 'small' || nextId == 'large'){
                articles++;
                obj = obj.next()
                nextId = obj.attr('id');
                //alert(nextId);
            }
            myClass.followArticles = articles;
            alert(myClass .sections);
        }
    });
}
```